# show vertical scrollbar of jscrollpane at the top

Tags: java, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane containing a JPanel.JPanel consist of one JCombobox,one JTextfield,4 JTextarea whose values are depend on selected item in combobox. Problem is vertical scrollbar of scrollpane always start at the bottom.

I tried with

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
```

and also tried with

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0,0));
```

but nothing seems work.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the call `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);` in SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to let content layout be done first.